# ISC Bind bind to non-local IP

Tags: linux, bind

I need to get ISC Bind to bind to a non-local IP on Linux. I have `net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind=1` set but unfortunately Bind's bind code seems to treat `listen-on-v6` as more of a whitelist of what addresses it's allowed to bind to rather than an actual list of IPs to bind to. Is there some way to make the `listen-on-v6` directive behave more like other server applications? The reason I'm looking to achieve this is because these bind instances are anycasted and while it is possible to use address labels to control Linux source address selection ideally I'd like to achieve a similar setup to what I use with nginx which is to not have the anycast IP present on an interface at all.

Comment: Yes, this directive defines a filter, it's not an imperative "where to listen". But for what you are needing it? If you are planning this for some kind of HA setup, just make it [call `rndc reconfig`](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-workers/2010-October/002922.html) after the newborn "primary" machine has a new address assigned; it will start listening on this new address without costly reloading of all zones. And, for the future, search mailing lists too, the answer long time exists in the wild as you can see.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov unfortunately that won't work for me. My use case is anycasting. Specifically I have an anycast address that I want bind to listen on and exists in Linux's "local" routing table allowing the instance to respond but I don't want it assigned to an interface as that causes some headaches mostly around it being selected as an outbound address but since it's anycasted that obviously is undesirable. My workaround is to set address labels to avoid it being selected but it'd be easier to just not have it on an interface at all like some of my other anycast addresses.

Comment: Linux uses *routing hints* to control which address gets selected for outbound when there are many. And, normally you *do* assign the anycast address to the interface, as if it was a normal IP, and *let* it be selected as outbound address when it is decided so by the system. That way or another, this is the most important detail and it must be present in the question, not just in a comment.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I'm aware of how Linux decides to select addresses and as noted I have this working by using address labels to avoid selecting the anycast address but it's not as clean as I'd like. For example my nginx load balancers are anycasted but the address doesn't need to be on the interface because non-local binds work properly. Ultimately there is no situation where these addresses should be used outside of responding to a query and a non-local bind is the cleanest setup in my mind to achieve that. There are other ways(I'm currently using them) but they're far cludgier IMO.

Comment: When you ask questions, it is expected you are ready to change your mind sometimes. Why asking if you're already decided what would be the answer? // About edition of the question: I voted to close it since it lacks important details. The rule here is to *put all relevant details into the question*.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I originally left out the details because they're sort of irrelevant to the the question. I know what I'm looking to achieve and the why is less important but since you disagree I've added it. That being said I don't have the answer. I came here in search of the answer. Yes, I have this working but the solution is a cludge and far uglier than I'd like. I came here to find a more elegant solution to my problem. I don't understand why you'd vote to close this question, it's still a question that should be answered. I'd like an answer and I can't be the only one.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov hopefully someone comes and answers this. If not it looks like NSD supports this feature trivially so guess I'll be looking to move DNS servers.